# Razor Page C# ASP.NET Core get Windows Username (Windows Auth)

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, windows-authentication, razor-pages

I have a problem with Windows authentication. I created a new web app with the command "dotnet new webapp --auth Windows". This should have a Windows authentication which works so far with the template. Now I would like to work with the Windows Username. On the Razor Pages (.cshtml) I can access the username with @User.Identity.Name without any problems. How do I get access to the username in the (.cshtml.cs) files.

The following attempts were made:

`Enviroment.UserName` --> works fine on local machine but not on IIS.

`User.Identity.Name` - The name "User" does not exist in the current context

`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

`HttpContext.Current.User` - The name "HttpContext" does not exist in the current context

`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`

My Application will run on IIS on Windows Server with Windows Authentication on.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance and have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` into your controllers/services, like this:

Startup.cs, `ConfigureServices` function:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

In your controller/service:

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public ProjectionSqlService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

    var username = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
}
```